# What is this airplane with small wings at different angles seen at Paphos Airport?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I landed in Paphos Airport in Cyprus and spotted this thing sitting in the sun near the runway. It has small 'wings' sticking out at different angles. What kind of plane is this? (Sorry for the bad photo.)

[image: strange plane]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like a [QAC Quickie Q2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QAC_Quickie_Q2). It's a [kit plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebuilt_aircraft) with over 2,000 produced.

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rutan_quickie_q2.jpg))

Comment: It's got the VG array that was a necessary bandaid for the old U of Glasgow canard airfoil to fix the pitch down in rain problem.

Comment: I should have guessed it was Rutan’s design. Beautiful yet strange …

Comment: @hdrz I've been a long-time fan of this plane because it kind of looks like an X-wing in flight